# How to address controller in another namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller named `CustomerController` in namespace `Web.Controllers.Customer`; so the fullname is `Web.Controllers.Customer.CustomerController`.

I want to have a form in a sinple `NewUser` view which posts data to the method `Signup` of the afformentioned controller. But I don't know how to address the namespace in `@Html.BeginForm`. Any help?

```
@Html.BeginForm("Signup", "Customer") // How to specify the namesapce?
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify Area as a html parameter:

```
Html.BeginForm("Signup", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { area="AreaName" })
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. However, the correct overload is: `Html.BeginForm("Signup", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { area="AreaName" })`

Comment: You are right, was typing this from memory, did not check with the compiler. Updated the answer now